# How to separate a concatenated string when first word (same beginning string pattern) of every observation contains a different ending string in R?

Tags: regex, r, string, string-concatenation

In R I have a much larger data set with the issue I need to resolve.  So I have a data frame in R and the first word of every observation in the `Post` variable has a concatenated string.  Fortunately the beginning of the string contains the same word but the ending of the concatenated string is always different. Would anyone know of a function that can separate `Introduction` from the word it is connected (attached) to a string of words? In other words, how can you separate a concatenated string when first word ("`Introduction`" the same beginning string pattern)  of every observation contains a different ending string in R?

**UPDATE: complete and reproducible question**

```
 dat <- data.frame(author=c("a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "a", "a","a", "a", "c","c","c","c"),Post=c("Introductiontwo text", "IntroductionYoua need Introduction to give a complete and reproducible questionone text", "IntroductionYouas need Introduction to give a complete and reproducible questionthre text", "IntroductionYouasd need Introduction to give a complete and reproducible questionnice text", "IntroductionYouasds need Introduction to give a complete and reproducible questionwow text", "IntroductionYouasdsh need Introduction to give a complete and reproducible questionone text", "IntroductionYouasdshs need Introduction to give a complete and reproducible questionone text", "IntroductionYouasdshsa need Introduction to give a complete and reproducible questionone text", "IntroductionYouasdshsas need Introduction to give a complete and reproducible questionone text", "IntroductionYouasdshsasa need Introduction to give a complete and reproducible questionone text","IntroductionYouasdshsasaa need Introduction to give a complete and reproducible questionone text", "IntroductionYouasdshsasaaa need Introduction to give a complete and reproducible questionone text","IntroductionYouasdshsasaaa need Introduction to give a complete and reproducible questionone text", "IntroductionYouasdshsasaaa need Introduction to give a complete and reproducible questionone text","IntroductionYouasdshsasaaa need Introduction to give a complete and reproducible questionone text", "IntroductionYouasdshsasaaa need Introduction to give a complete and reproducible questionone text","IntroductionYouasdshsasaaa need Introduction to give a complete and reproducible questionone text", "IntroductionYouasdshsasaaa need Introduction to give a complete and reproducible questionone text"))


dat

         author                                                                                              Post
1       a                                                                              Introductiontwo text
2       b           IntroductionYoua need Introduction to give a complete and reproducible questionone text
3       c         IntroductionYouas need Introduction to give a complete and reproducible questionthre text
4       d        IntroductionYouasd need Introduction to give a complete and reproducible questionnice text
5       a        IntroductionYouasds need Introduction to give a complete and reproducible questionwow text
6       b       IntroductionYouasdsh need Introduction to give a complete and reproducible questionone text
7       c      IntroductionYouasdshs need Introduction to give a complete and reproducible questionone text
8       d     IntroductionYouasdshsa need Introduction to give a complete and reproducible questionone text
9       e    IntroductionYouasdshsas need Introduction to give a complete and reproducible questionone text
10      a   IntroductionYouasdshsasa need Introduction to give a complete and reproducible questionone text
11      a  IntroductionYouasdshsasaa need Introduction to give a complete and reproducible questionone text
12      a IntroductionYouasdshsasaaa need Introduction to give a complete and reproducible questionone text
13      a IntroductionYouasdshsasaaa need Introduction to give a complete and reproducible questionone text
14      a IntroductionYouasdshsasaaa need Introduction to give a complete and reproducible questionone text
15      c IntroductionYouasdshsasaaa need Introduction to give a complete and reproducible questionone text
16      c IntroductionYouasdshsasaaa need Introduction to give a complete and reproducible questionone text
17      c IntroductionYouasdshsasaaa need Introduction to give a complete and reproducible questionone text
18      c IntroductionYouasdshsasaaa need Introduction to give a complete and reproducible questionone text
```

Comment: What if another `Introduction` is located in the same observation? Wouldn't that affect the non-concatenated Introduction by adding an extra white space?  That is why I said I have a larger data set that is similar to my example.

Comment: So why not produce a sample presenting this case, if it occurs!? Really, I don't understand.

Comment: @RobertDove You need to give a complete and reproducible question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  What would be your approach?

Comment: I was blown out of the water on this question.  Then again, I was riding the subway while using a cell phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `gsub` with capture groups

```
gsub("(Introduction)(.+)","\\1 \\2", dat$Post)
```

The parenthesis captures the "Introduction" and the following characters. Then we replace them with the matched values with a space inbetween.